# Checked Items is undefined on selection React JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to read all checked items and storying that value to `selectedTransaction`.

Issue is when I check the 1st item, it throws `undefined` error & for the selection of the 2nd Item it shows 1 array item in the console log.

But if I console log the `selectedTransactions`, it shows correct item values.

What I'm doing wrong here. Please help

```
  const [selectedTransaction, setSelectedTransaction] = useState<any>();

  const handleCheckboxOnChange = (
    transactionDetails: TransactionDetail,
    isCheckeds: boolean,
  ) => {

    const selectedTransactions = transactionsList.transactionDetails
      .filter((item: TransactionDetail) => item.isChecked === true);
    setSelectedTransaction(selectedTransactions);

    console.log(selectedTransactions); // Shows 1 selected Item 
    console.log(selectedTransaction); // Shows undefined 
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

State is not updated immediately (its asynchronous and batched), thats why you are getting `undefined` or the previous state

```
setSelectedTransaction(selectedTransactions);
console.log(selectedTransactions); // Shows 1 selected Item 
console.log(selectedTransaction); // Shows undefined
```

Use a useEffect to console state when data is changed. Give the dependency array `[selectedTransaction]`

```
useEffect(()=>{
    console.log(selectedTransaction); 
}, [selectedTransaction]);
```